# ARIMA modelling, prediction and plotting with CO2 dataset in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am working with `arima0()` and `co2`. I would like to plot `arima0()` model over my data. I have tried `fitted()` and `curve()` with no success.

Here is my code:

```
###### Time Series

# format: time series
data(co2)

# format: matrix
dmn <- list(month.abb, unique(floor(time(co2))))
co2.m <- matrix(co2, 12, dimnames = dmn)

co2.dt <- pracma::detrend(co2.m, tt = 'linear')
co2.dt <- ts(as.numeric(co2.dt), start = c(1959,1), frequency=12)

# first diff
co2.dt.dif <- diff(co2.dt,lag = 12)

# Second diff
co2.dt.dif2 <- diff(co2.dt.dif,lag = 1)
```

With the data prepared, I ran the following `arima0`:

```
results <- arima0(co2.dt.dif2, order = c(2,0,0), method = "ML")
resultspredict <- predict(results, n.ahead = 36)
```

I would like to plot the model and the prediction. I am hoping there is a way to do this in base R. I would also like to be able to plot the predictions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Session 2: A better idea for time series modelling**

In previous session, we have seen the difficulty in prediction if we separate de-trending and modelling of de-trended series. Now, we try to combine those two stages in one go.

The seasonal pattern of `co2` is really strong, so we need a seasonal differencing anyway:

```
data(co2)
co2dt <- diff(co2, lag = 12)
par(mfrow = c(1,2)); ts.plot(co2dt); acf(co2dt)
```

[image]

After this seasonal differencing, `co2dt` does not look stationary. So we need further a non-seasonal differencing.

```
co2dt.dif <- diff(co2dt)
par(mfrow = c(1,2)); ts.plot(co2dt.dif); acf(co2dt.dif)
```

[image]

The negative spikes within season and between season suggest that a MA process is needed for both. I will not work with `co2dt.dif`; we can work with `co2` directly:

```
fit <- arima0(co2, order = c(0,1,1), seasonal = c(0,1,1))
acf(fit$residuals)
```

[image]

Now the residuals are perfectly uncorrelated! So we have an `ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,1)[12]` model for `co2` series.

---

As usual, fitted values are obtained by subtracting residuals from data:

```
co2fitted <- co2 - fit$residuals
```

Predictions are made by a single call to `predict`:

```
co2pred <- predict(fit, n.ahead = 36, se.fit = FALSE)
```

Let's plot them together:

```
ts.plot(co2, co2fitted, co2pred, col = 1:3)
```

[image]

Oh, this is just gorgeous!

Answer (score 2):

**Session 1: To begin with...**

To be honest, I am pretty much worried about your way in modelling `co2` time series. Something wrong happened already when you de-trended `co2`. Why use `tt = "linear"`? You fit a linear trend within each period (i.e., year), and take the residuals for further inspection. This is often not recommended as it tends to introduce artificial effects to the residual series. I would incline to do `tt = "constant"`, i.e., simply dropping off yearly average. This would at least preserve the with-season correlation as in the original data.

Perhaps you want to see some evidence here. Consider using ACF to help you diagnose.

```
data(co2)

## de-trend by dropping yearly average (no need to use `pracma::detrend`)
yearlymean <- ave(co2, gl(39, 12), FUN = mean)
co2dt <- co2 - yearlymean

## de-trend by dropping within season linear trend
co2.m <- matrix(co2, 12)
co2.dt <- pracma::detrend(co2.m, tt = "linear")
co2.dt <- ts(as.numeric(co2.dt), start = c(1959, 1), frequency = 12)

## compare time series and ACF
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
ts.plot(co2dt); acf(co2dt)
ts.plot(co2.dt); acf(co2.dt)
```

[image]

Both de-trended series have strong seasonal effect, thus a further seasonal differencing is required.

```
## seasonal differencing
co2dt.dif <- diff(co2dt, lag = 12)
co2.dt.dif <- diff(co2.dt, lag = 12)

## compare time series and ACF
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
ts.plot(co2dt.dif); acf(co2dt.dif)
ts.plot(co2.dt.dif); acf(co2.dt.dif)
```

[image]

The ACF for `co2.dt.dif` has more significant negative correlations. This is the sign of over-de-trending. So we prefer to `co2dt`. `co2dt` is already stationary, and no more differencing is needed (otherwise you just over-difference it and introduce more negative autocorrelation).

The big negative spike at lag 1 for ACF of `co2dt.dif` suggests that we want seasonal MA. Also, the positive spike with the season implies a mild AR process in general. So consider:

```
## we exclude mean because we found estimation of mean is 0 if we include it
fit <- arima0(co2dt.dif, order = c(1,0,0), seasonal = c(0,0,1), include.mean = FALSE)
```

Whether this model is doing good, we need to inspect ACF of residuals:

```
acf(fit$residuals)
```

[image]

Looks like this model is decent (actually pretty great).

For prediction purpose, it is actually a better idea to integrate seasonal differencing of `co2dt` with model fitting of `co2dt.dif`. Let's do

```
fit <- arima0(co2dt, order = c(1,0,0), seasonal = c(0,1,1), include.mean = FALSE)
```

This will give exactly as same estimate for AR and MA coefficients as above two-stage work, but now prediction is fairly easy to be dealt with a single `predict` call.

```
## 3 years' ahead prediction (no prediction error; only mean)
predco2dt <- predict(fit, n.ahead = 36, se.fit = FALSE)
```

Let's plot `co2dt`, fitted model and prediction together:

```
fittedco2dt <- co2dt - fit$residuals
ts.plot(co2dt, fittedco2dt, predco2dt, col = 1:3)
```

[image]

The result looks very promising!

Now the final stage, is to actually map this back to the original `co2` series. For fitted values, we just add back the yearly mean we have dropped off:

```
fittedco2 <- fittedco2dt + yearlymean
```

But for prediction it is more difficult, because we don't know what yearly mean in the future would be. In this regard, our modelling though looks good, is not practically useful. I will talk about a better idea in another answer. To finish this session, we plot `co2` with its fitted values only:

```
ts.plot(co2, fittedco2, col = 1:2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Session 3: Model selection**

The story should have finished by now; but I would like to make a comparison with `auto.arima` from `forecast`, that can automatically decide on the "best" model.

```
library(forecast)
autofit <- auto.arima(co2)

#Series: co2 
#ARIMA(1,1,1)(1,1,2)[12]                    
#
#Coefficients:
#         ar1      ma1     sar1     sma1     sma2
#      0.2569  -0.5847  -0.5489  -0.2620  -0.5123
#s.e.  0.1406   0.1204   0.5880   0.5701   0.4819
#
#sigma^2 estimated as 0.08576:  log likelihood=-84.39
#AIC=180.78   AICc=180.97   BIC=205.5
```

`auto.arima` has chosen `ARIMA(1,1,1)(1,1,2)[12]`, which is much more complicated as it involves both seasonal differencing and non-seasonal differencing.

Our model based on step-by-step investigation suggests an `ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,1)[12]`:

```
fit <- arima0(co2, order = c(0,1,1), seasonal = c(0,1,1))

#Call:
#arima0(x = co2, order = c(0, 1, 1), seasonal = c(0, 1, 1))
#
#Coefficients:
#      ma1     sma1
#  -0.3495  -0.8515
#s.e.   0.0497   0.0254
#
#sigma^2 estimated as 0.08262:  log likelihood = -85.98,  aic = 177.96
```

AIC values suggest our model better. So does BIC:

```
BIC = -2 * loglik + log(n) * p
```

We have `n <- length(co2)` data, and `p <- length(fit$coef) + 1` parameters (the additional one for `sigma2`), thus our model has BIC

```
-2 * fit$loglik + log(n) * p
# [1] 196.5503
```

So, `auto.arima` has over-fitted data.

In fact, as soon as we see `ARIMA(1,1,1)(1,1,2)[12]`, we have strong suspicion for its over-fitting. Because different effects "cancel off" each other. This happens to the additional seasonal MA and non-seasonal AR introduced by `auto.arima`, as AR introduces positive autocorrelation while MA introduces negative one.